# Firefox Addon (Observer) http-on-modify-request does not get triggered

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, header, mozilla

Im trying to write a really simpe Addon using jpm and a text editor, however i run into this problem:

i got this code to observe HTTP Request Headers:

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

console.log("inside test");

var httpRequestObserver = {
  observer: function(subject, topic, data){

    console.log("inside observer definition");
    if(topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
      var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

      console.log("done what i should do");
    }
  },

  get observerService(){
    console.log("registered");
    return Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
  },

  register: function(){
    console.log("registering");
    this.observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false);
  },

  unregister: function(){
    console.log("unregistering");
    this.observerService.removeObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request");
  }
};

exports.httpRequestObserver = httpRequestObserver;
```

and run this from another .js file like this:

```
require("./theothercode.js").httpRequestObserver.register();
```

However, my output in the console looks like this:

```
console.log: myplugin: inside test
console.log: myplugin: inside main
console.log: myplugin: registering
console.log: myplugin: registered
```

And then it just stops doing anything, even when im randomly surfing the web (what should produce some decent amount of Headers and thus should trigger my 'observer' function).

Am i missing something? im still new to Java Script and not really liking it..
I have read through some Mozilla Guides and also other posts regarding this, but they do not seem to have the same problem as me.

To conclude: my observer() function does never run, why?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found the answer, and i REALLY dont know why this is so, but well, here it comes:

the 'observer' function how its called in my code needs to be called 'observe'.

really - annoying.